# Finding Exact word between tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

With reference to [URL](https://m.fedex.com/mt/www.fedex.com/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=758283215108703&cntry_code=fedextrack&locale=en_US&un_jtt_redirect) I am searching text Service but it is also searching  **Signature Service not requested**. I am using following code to get desired result but somehow it is not matching exact word

```
serviceElement = soup.findAll('div', text=re.compile('Service'))
```

Is there anyway I can mention both class name and desire string in `findAll()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did find a way to do it. Applying Simple RegEx Rule.

```
serviceElement = soup.findAll('div', text=re.compile('^Service$'))
```

Just not removing this post incase it could be helpful for someone else.